# Find surface area of a figure defined by: $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 \leq 1$ , $x^2 + y^2 \leq y $, $y + z \geq 1$

Tags: calculus

Find surface area of a figure defined by: $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 \leq 1$ , $x^2 + y^2 \leq y $, $y + z \geq 1$.

I drew the picture and found two surfaces: $S_1$ and $S_2$,

where $S_1$ is $\{ 0 \leq y \leq 1 \land -\sqrt{(\frac{1}{2})^2 - (y-\frac{1}{2})^2} \leq x \leq \sqrt{(\frac{1}{2})^2 - (y-\frac{1}{2})^2} \} \cap y + z = 1 \} $

and

$S_2$ is $\{ x^2 + y^2 + z^2 \leq 1 \cap x^2 + y^2 \leq y \} $ .

I wonder if this is correct:

$P(S_1) = \begin{gather*}
    \iint_D \sqrt{1+ 0^2 +(-1)^2}\,dx\,dy = ... = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{4}\pi
\end{gather*}
$

and

$P(S_2) = \begin{gather*}
    \iint_D \sqrt{1+ \frac{x^2}{1-x^2 - y^2} +  \frac{y^2}{1-x^2 - y^2}} \,dx\,dy = \cdots =\pi
\end{gather*}
$

In both cases $D$ is $\{ -\frac{1}{2} \leq x \leq  \frac{1}{2} $ and $ \frac{1}{2} - \sqrt{(\frac{1}{2})^2 - x^2}  \leq y \leq  \frac{1}{2} + \sqrt{(\frac{1}{2})^2 - x^2}\}$

Could someone please say if the idea is good, and if it isn't, what other approach should I take?
I am most familiar with this one.
Thanks in advance.

**EDIT **
There was a mistake in text above, I've corrected it.

Comment: There should be a third surface

Comment: I've edited the post, I made a mistake in task setting. It should be x+z >= 1, not x+ y >=1.

Answer (score 1):

In cylindrical coordinates, the cylinder $x^2 + y^2 = y \ $ is

$r^2 = r \sin \theta \implies r = \sin \theta, \ 0 \leq \theta \leq \pi$.

This is a cylinder of radius $\frac{1}{2}$ with center at $(0,\frac{1}{2})$.

Now parametrization of cylinder is

$r(\theta, z) = (r\cos\theta, r\sin\theta, z) = (\frac{1}{2} \sin 2\theta, \sin^2\theta, z)$

$|r'_\theta \times r'_z| = 1$

Also note that at the intersection of the cylinder and the plane $y +z = 1$,

$\sin^2\theta + z = 1 \implies z = \cos^2\theta$

Also the intersection of the cylinder and the sphere $ \ \sin^2\theta + z^2 = 1 \implies z = \pm \cos\theta$

So the integral to find surface area of the cylindrical surface satisfying the given condition is

$\displaystyle 2 \int_{0}^{\pi/2} \int_{\cos^2\theta}^{\cos\theta} dz \ d\theta$

You may have to find for other surfaces similarly. The integral for other surfaces based on their parametrization are given by,

For spherical surface: $\displaystyle \int_0^{\pi} \int_0^{\sin\theta} \frac{r}{\sqrt{1-r^2}} \ dr \ d\theta$

For planar bottom: $\displaystyle \int_0^{\pi} \int_0^{\sin\theta} \sqrt2 \ r \ dr \ d\theta$

Comment: Let me know any questions you have. I added integral for other two surfaces as well. Your first integral in cartesian which finds the surface area of the planar bottom is correct. But the next one which is spherical top is wrong. Your answer says $\pi$ but for a unit sphere, $\pi$ will be the surface area of the whole sphere for $y \geq 0, z \geq 0$ so obviously that is incorrect. Your bounds seem fine but you may not have applied it correctly. But I think it is much easier to do this question in cylindrical coordinates.

Comment: Lastly your working misses the third surface which is vertical cylindrical surface that is present between the planar bottom and the spherical top.